# convert list of items to dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a list `l` containing 1000's of items. I want to convert it to dataframe as shown below.

l

```
$apple
        leftside           rightside
A          2                4
B          3                4
C          5                3

$orange

       leftside           rightside
D          1                2
E          1                2
F          5                3
```

result

```
        leftside           rightside
apple
A          2                4
B          3                4
C          5                3
orange
D          1                2
E          1                2
F          5                3
```

here is the dput for real data:

```
structure(list(`1010901` = structure(c(0L, 2L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 0L, 
10L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 0L), .Dim = c(21L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("AAK1", "AK2", "ANKRD30BL", "CBFA2T3", "CLCC1", "DFNB59", 
    "DPP10", "DSCR4", "FBXO42", "FRG1JP", "HFM1", "INPP5D", "LIN28A", 
    "NOTCH2", "NOTCH2NL", "PID1", "PKP4", "PMF1", "RUNX1", "SET", 
    "YARS"), c("Left.Gene.Symbols", "Right.Gene.Symbols")), .Names = c("", 
"")), class = "table"), `1028701` = structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 2L), .Dim = c(9L, 
2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("ADIPOR2", "ANKRD30BL", "CKAP5", 
"EXD1", "HSPE1", "KDM5A", "NUP98", "PSMG3-AS1", "PTN"), c("Left.Gene.Symbols", 
"Right.Gene.Symbols")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")), .Names = c("1010901", 
"1028701"))
```

Comment: SO is here to help you get code that you've already written to work, by helping you solve specific and atomic problems. The prerequisite to asking here is having some code you've written, and showing effort and persistence on your part.

Comment: If you tried and failed, what did you try and why do you think it failed? What are you still unclear on, what is your best guess at how to solve the problem?

Comment: @Andrew G `do.call(rbind,l)
Error in .Method(..., deparse.level = deparse.level) : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 5)`

Comment: @thelatemail `data.frame(Reduce(rbind, l))` this also failed. I haven't worked with list much.

Comment: @MAPK - by the looks of that error message, you have different numbers of columns in the parts in your list, which might be matrices and not data.frames.

Comment: @thelatemail That is right if any of the leftside or  rightside has nothing in it, then the column is missing in that list. How do I force merge that by adding NAs?

Comment: can you put the output of `dput(l[c(1,2)])` in the question?

Comment: @jeremycg please see the edit for dput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` ('lst'), create the first row as blank (using `rbind`), change the row names with the names of the `lst` element, and then `rbind` all the `list` elements together with `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
    nm1 <- names(lst)[i]
   rbind(`row.names<-` (data.frame(leftside='', rightside='', 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE), nm1), lst[[i]])}))
#           leftside rightside
#apple                    
#A             2         4
#B             3         4
#C             5         3
#orange                   
#D             1         2
#E             1         2
#F             5         3
```

NOTE: By creating the `''` as the first row, we are basically changing the `numeric` class to `character`.  I am not sure why this format is required but I assume that the OP have a definite reason to proceed with this.

#### data

```
lst <- structure(list(apple = structure(list(leftside = c(2L,
3L, 5L
), rightside = c(4L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("leftside", 
"rightside"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B", "C")), 
orange = structure(list(
leftside = c(1L, 1L, 5L), rightside = c(2L, 2L, 3L)),
.Names = c("leftside", 
"rightside"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
 c("D", "E", "F"))), .Names = c("apple", "orange"))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(l, .id='list_name')
```